# Can an if/else statement be used with a click function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an image map with two different area shape attributes. I want to great Google Analytic tracking events onClick on the image map depending on the shape attribute clicked.

I've tried this:

```
$('area').val('shape').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).val() == 'rect') {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'test category', 'test action', 'rect shape clicked']);
  }

  else if ($(this).val() == 'poly') {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'test category', 'test action', 'poly shape clicked']);
  }

}); ​
```

But this doesn't work. Can an if else statement be used on a click function?

Comment: Do you have an error message somewhere?

Comment: can't use `val()` method for `area` tag ...what is that supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in your use of `val()`.   `shape` is an attribute of `area` tag.

following should work

```
$('area').click(function(e) {

 var shape=$(this).attr('shape');
  e.preventDefault();
  if (shape == 'rect') {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'test category', 'test action', 'rect shape clicked']);
  }

  else if (shape == 'poly') {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'test category', 'test action', 'poly shape clicked']);
  }

}); ​
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see where I went totally wrong. Huge help providing the corrected code. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only calling your function if val = shape.  Then you are testing that same element if it's val is a rect or a poly. It will always be neither because you just clarified that it is shape. Perhaps you should be using .attr or .has to select only shapes being clicked on rather than .val then proceed to test that shape's val is either rect or poly.

Can you post the HTML of a few areas so I can confirm my assumptions?